# How to correctly get timestamps in each stage of the ELK cluster?

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, apache-kafka

I have this pipeline up running on AWS:

Webserver+rsyslog->Kafka (3 servers: 1xZK, 2xKafka Brokers)->Logstash (2 servers: Both acting as indexers)->ES+Kibana (both on the one server).

Here is the log I send from rsyslog:

```
{"rsyslog_timestamp":"2016-05-19T03:00:55.586137+00:00", "message":"<IP_REMOVED> - - 2016-05-19T03:00:55:586082 \"GET \/investing\/property\/national-diversified-property?user=user361 HTTP\/1.1\" 301 681"}
```

Here is an example of a log when viewed in Kibana:

```
rsyslog_timestamp:May 19th 2016, 13:15:27.023 message:<IP_REMOVED> - - 2016-05-19T03:15:27:023436 "GET /banking/savings-account/netbank-saver?user=user559 HTTP/1.1" 301 659 @version:1 @timestamp:May 19th 2016, 13:17:32.591 category:banking subcategory:savings-account product:netbank-saver user:user559 _id:<REMOVED> _type:logs _index:logstash-2016.05.19 _score:
```

So I have a timestamps on:
1. Apache log
2. Rsyslog (but somewhere this is being modified, maybe logstash?)
3. I don't know where the others come from is it LS or ES?

I want to clearly have the timestamps on Kafka (I have installed the RC4 but I can't see timestamps), LS, ES. That way I can see the time it takes to get through each part.

How can I do this in the remaining parts? And what is messing with my rsyslog timestamp and modifing it?

Comment: The additional `@timestamp` you see is added by Logstash at the time it receives and processes your log line. As for adding a timestamp in Kafka, it is not yet supported, but it is a [work in progress](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/KIP-32+-+Add+timestamps+to+Kafka+message). Until then, you'll need to add this in your producer code.

Comment: It may be confusing that you are showing two different logs, could you give an example of one log event at the start and end of your processing pipeline?

Comment: Ok I will edit that over the w/e, when I spin up the cluster.